# Data passed back to callback in Angular is undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, asynchronous

I have this endpoint in Node.js:

```
usersRoute.get('/get', function(req, res) {

    //If no date was passed in - just use todays date

    var date    = req.query.date || dateFormat(new Date(), 'yyyy-mm-dd'),
        search  = req.query.search;

    users.getAllUsers(date, search)
        .then(function(results) {
           res.json(results); 
        }, function(err) {
            res.status(500).json({
                success: false, 
                message: 'Server error.',
                data: []
            });
        });
});
```

For testing purposes, I wrongly named my SQL table, so it will go to the `function(err){}`

The function in my Service looks like this

```
function getUsers(date, search) {
            return $http.get('/api/users/get', {
                params: {
                    date: UtilsService.formatDate(date),
                    search: search
                }
            })
            .then(getData)
            .catch(handleErr);

            function getData(response) {
                console.log(response);
                return response.data;
            }

            function handleErr(err) {
                console.log(err);
                LoggerService.error('Could not retrieve users.', err ,'Ooops');
                return $q.reject(err);
            }
        }
```

Both of the `console.log` in `then` and `catch` returns `undefined`.

I'd appreciate it if anyone can explain to me why this is.

**Edit** For clarfication; Here are more backend code:

**Users.js**

```
var sql     = require('seriate'); 
var when    = require('when');

var getAllUsers = function(date, search) {
     return sql.execute({
        query: sql.fromFile('../sql/users/getAllUsers.sql'),
        params: { 
            date: { 
                type: sql.DATE, 
                val: date 
            },
            search: {
                type: sql.VARCHAR,
                val: search
            }
        }
    });
}


module.exports = {
    getAllUsers: getAllUsers
};
```

**UsersApi.js**

```
var express         = require('express');
var dateFormat      = require('dateformat');
var users           = require('../models/users');
var validation      = require('../middleware/validation');

var usersRoute = express.Router();

//Checks for a valid token 
validation.isLoggedIn(usersRoute);


usersRoute.get('/get', function(req, res) {

    //If no date was passed in - just use todays date

    var date    = req.query.date || dateFormat(new Date(), 'yyyy-mm-dd'),
        search  = req.query.search;

    users.getAllUsers(date, search)
        .then(function(results) {
           res.json(results); 
        }, function(err) {
            res.status(500).json({
                success: false, 
                message: 'Server error.',
                data: []
            });
        });
});

module.exports = usersRoute;
```

In my service, the `then` part as well as the `catch` is visited, and both objects (`response` and `err`) is `undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you share the full service? I created a [plunker with your code](https://plnkr.co/edit/VYxkxaxT1LtBrirZI55x?p=preview) that calls a nodejs service I am hosting on OpenShift based on the sample you provided I created a method that simulate your function(err):

```
self.routes['/get'] = function(req, res) {
    res.status(500).json({
        success: false,
        message: 'Server error.',
        data: []
    });
};
```

The app on plunker is:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.service('UserService', function($http, $q) {
  this.getUsers = function(date, search) {
    return $http.get('https://nodejs-starters.rhcloud.com/get', {
        params: {
          date: date,
          search: search
        }
      })
      .then(getData)
      .catch(handleErr);
  }

  function getData(response) {
    console.log('status: ' + reponse.status + ' - ' + response.message);
    return response.data;
  }

  function handleErr(err) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
    console.log('status: ' + err.status + ' Err= ' + err.data.message);
    console.log('Could not retrieve users.', err.data.message, 'Ooops');
    return $q.reject(err);
  }
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http, $q, UserService) {
  var vm = $scope;
  vm.name = 'World';
  UserService.getUsers(new Date(), '*');

});
```

And, the console shows the following results:

```
app.js:21 {"data":{"success":false,"message":"Server error.","data":[]},"status":500,"config":{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"params":{"date":"2016-06-02T18:33:50.633Z","search":"*"},"url":"https://nodejs-starters.rhcloud.com/get","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"}},"statusText":"Internal Server Error"}
app.js:22 status: 500 Err= Server error.
app.js:23 Could not retrieve users. Server error. Ooops
```

So the handleErr is called and err is defined. 'err.data.success' is false and 'err.data.message' is 'Server error.' as you wrote on nodejs.

In the plunker example, can you replace my URL https://nodejs-starters.rhcloud.com/get with your's and see if you get the same result or a different result?

Comment: I'm running on localhost right now, and Plunkr didn't like requests that wasn't https. But I'll add some more code for clarity

Comment: @Nilzone-Thanks. I created a [github](https://github.com/gregorifaroux/nodejsexample) with my example with both nodejs express and angularjs that you can test locally. You can clone it, then cd nodejsexample, then npm install, and then node server.js and open a browser to the indicated URL 127.0.0.1:8080. That replaces my plunker and open shift example. Then, you can try to add your modules and see if the error occurs. If you can push to github, so I can see the error. If not, I will try to plug your modules but I am traveling the next few days, so I won't have time until Monday

Comment: I'll just accept your answer. It seems to work when i made a new endpoint just for testing, so I'll find my bug soon enough. Thanks for all your help though :)